# How do I prove the definition of a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, function-and-relation-composition

The question is asking me to prove that $f(a \circ b) = f(a) \circ f(b)$.

This I believe is referencing our previous proof which tells us: 
Assume $g:x \rightarrow y $ is a bijection and for an $a \in S(X)$ set $f(a)= g \circ a \circ g^{-1}$ and then I proved $f$ is a bijective function from $S(X)$ to $S(Y)$.

We haven't been given any background on homomorphisms so I'm a little unsure on how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Here's a quick guide on how to write math on this site: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f(ab)=gabg^{-1}=ga1bg^{-1}=gag^{-1}gbg^{-1}=\cdots$?

Comment: That makes sense. How is f(ab) equal to f(a o b)?

Comment: @user104203 $ab$ is shorthand for $a\circ b$. In general, when the operation is understood, the operation is simply denoted juxtaposition of elements. Sorry for being lazy =)

Comment: Oh okay, 100% clear now. Thank you!